# Expanding singular cell into multiple rows based on number in the cell - EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba, math, numbers

I have a spreadsheet containing a column of numbers.

For every value within the reference column, I need the to excel to produce a row of number in the adjacent column with values starting from the number 1, incrementally increasing by 1 and ending once the reference value is reach. This then needs to be repeated for the next value in the reference column and so on, continuing to expand in the adjacent column.

Below is an example of the reference column containing 3 values and what i did manually adjacent. Can some please help me write function in VBA so that i dont need to do this manually.
[image: example of what i need the function to do]

Thanks for the help in advanced.

Answer (score 4):

```
Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range, i As Long
    For Each cell In Range("I2", Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp))
        For i = 1 To cell.Value
            Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = i
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @S.Dorrah, any feedback?

Answer (score 4):

Larger grouped series would benefit from an array.

```
sub main()
    dim i as long, j as long, k as long, vals as variant

    redim vals(1 to application.sum(range(cells(2, "i"), cells(rows.count, "i").end(xlup))), 1 to 1)

    for i=2 to cells(rows.count, "i").end(xlup).row
        for j=1 to cells(i, "i").value2
            k=k+1
            vals(k, 1) = j
        next j
    next i

    cells(2, "j").resize(ubound(vals, 1), ubound(vals, 2)) = vals
end sub
```

Comment: how would I go about running it. Ive place it into a script and pressing run however nothing happens.... the code however makes sense!

Comment: I've wrapped it in standard sub procedure syntax. I assure you that it was tested before posting.

Answer (score 2):

Or with arrays

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim arr(), i As Long, j As Long, output As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        arr = .Range("I2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp)).Value
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            j = 0
            Do While j < arr(i, 1)
                j = j + 1
                output = output & CStr(j) & ","
            Loop
        Next i
        .Range("J2").Resize(UBound(Split(output, ",")), 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Split(output, ","))
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't allow you to go beyond last Excel row

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ExpandReferenceNumbers()
    Const REF_COL = 9 'I
    Dim arr As Variant, lr As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim maxRows As Long, maxVal As Long, maxXLRows As Long

    maxXLRows = Rows.Count
    lr = Sheet1.Cells(maxXLRows, REF_COL).End(xlUp).Row

    arr = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(2, REF_COL), Sheet1.Cells(lr, REF_COL))
    For i = 1 To lr - 1
        maxRows = maxRows + arr(i, 1)
    Next
    If maxRows > maxXLRows Then maxRows = maxXLRows - 2

    arr = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(2, REF_COL), Sheet1.Cells(maxRows + 1, REF_COL + 1))
    k = 1
    For i = 1 To lr
        For j = 1 To arr(i, 1)
            If k + j - 1 > maxRows Then Exit For
            arr(k + j - 1, 2) = j
        Next
        k = k + arr(i, 1)
    Next
    Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(2, REF_COL), Sheet1.Cells(maxRows + 1, REF_COL + 1)) = arr
End Sub
```

---

Result

[image: Result]